# usage of preposition in the given sentence

Tags: prepositions

What will be the prepositions in the blank spaces :

Vidyasagar lived in a rented house _____ forty seven years _____ his life in Kolkata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vid lived in a rented house for forty-seven years during his life in Kolkata.
Therefore: "for" and "during."

Answer (score 0):

Vidyasagar lived in a rented house *except for the* forty seven years *of* his life in Kolkata.